# Apple Push PHP: No all notifications received

Tags: php, mysql, ios, apple-push-notifications

I've a PHP-script with a MySQL-database for Apple Push Notification. The script works but not all notifications will receive their notification. Whats going wrong?

```
<?PHP

$db_user = "xx_fw"; // Gebruiker voor MySQL
$db_pass = "xxx"; // Wachtwoord voor MySQL
$db_host = "localhost"; // Host voor MySQL; standaard localhost
$db_db = "xx_fw"; // Database

// Als je al ergens anders een database connectie hebt gemaakt,
// maak dan van de volgende twee regels commentaar (# of // ervoor zetten)
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_db);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM iospush");

                                $deviceToken = ARRAY();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $deviceToken[] = $row["token"];
}

if($_POST['politie']){

    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    $politiemessage = "POLITIEBERICHT: ".$message;

    $payload = '{
                    "aps" : 

                        { "alert" : { "body" : "'.$politiemessage.'" },
"badge" : 1,
"sound" : "politiepush.wav"
                        } 
                }';


    $ssl='ios-ssl.pem';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ssl);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxx');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if(!$fp){
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Notifications sent!";
    }

    $devArray = array();
    $devArray[] = $deviceToken;

    foreach($deviceToken as $token){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        print "sending message :" . $payload . "n";

        fwrite($fp, $msg);
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Verstuurd aan: ".$token;
echo "<br><br>";

    }
    fclose($fp);

} else if($_POST['message']){

    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $payload = '{
                    "aps" : 

                        { "alert" : { "body" : "'.$message.'" },
"badge" : 1,
"sound" : "chime"
                        } 
                }';


    $ssl='ios-ssl.pem';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ssl);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxx');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if(!$fp){
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Notifications sent!";
    }

    $devArray = array();
    $devArray[] = $deviceToken;

    foreach($deviceToken as $token){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        print "sending message :" . $payload . "n";

        fwrite($fp, $msg);
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Verstuurd aan: ".$token;
echo "<br><br>";

    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Is the problem te way of sending the pushes, or is it going wrong on Apple's side?
Thanks!

Comment: remember Apple doesn't guarantee delivery of the message. Also, this is my experience, when I used the development push server, it sometimes didn't send notification or it sent it after significant delay.. Using production APNS it worked without these issues

Comment: But this is the production server, not the development..

Comment: Whats the output on screen that you see while running this script?

Comment: I'll see "Notification send! sending message : xx Verstuurd aan: xx" for every device in my database. No errors

Comment: I have an idea; How many devices there are in the DB? Are you absolutely sure, that this code will try to send the notification to EVERY device? I just thought, that maybe this script executes too long and your server has some limit on how long a script can take before it's killed; Normally these push server scripts are ran as daemons, not as something that responds to POST requests.

Comment: also can it happen that this script is code is called twice? (like two post requests coming very shortly after each other?) I think there's some limit on how many connections you can make to the Apple Push Server

Comment: Even if this doesn't solve the problem, I still think you don't want the push server to be started on POST request. I think it's best to keep the connection to Apple Server all the time and implement a queue (memcache queue ideally, DB is slow) from which you will poll notifications one after another; Doing it your way, one can easily do many POST requests on your server and easily block every notification from being sent! So just from security's point of view, this is not a good idea

Comment: There are 697 device in de DB. For all of those the script says "Send to xxx (token)". The SSL-certificate is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
                    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
                    if ($badge)
                    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
                    if ($sound)
                    $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;
                    /* End of Configurable Items */

                    $ctx = stream_context_create();
                    $a = stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',  dirname(__FILE__).'\push.pem');

                    // assume the private key passphase was removed.
                    // stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
                    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
                    //$status = array();
                    $status = '';
                    if ($fp) {
                         $status =  "Notification sent successfully."; //$message;
                    } else {
                    $status = "Failed to sent notification.";
                    //
                    }

                    $payload = json_encode($body);

                    $msg = @(chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ','' , $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload);

                    if($msg)
                    {
                        fwrite($fp, $msg);
                        if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
                        }
                    }
                    echo $status;
?>
```

Note# please use correct .pem file for ios

Comment: Where to change/add this? Can you made the full script please .